# Is it possible to talk about two different phonemes if they always have the same manifestations?

Tags: phonology, second-lang-acquisition

Both considering L1 speakers and L2 speakers.

It becomes a bit tricky involving L2 speakers. While a phoneme is defined as one of the units of sound that distinguishes one word from another in a particular language, it's not necessary that every aspects can satisfy for an L2 speaker.

1. The person was taught that /θ s/ are different sounds in English.
2. The person can distinguish /θ s/ by ear only carefully, e.g. distinguish *sink* and *think* pronounced alone and clearly.
3. The person can't pronounce them differently h'self.

There are other possibilities for the above factors. Can we argue the existence of a grey area or continuum?

About L1, is /u/ and /w/ an example, if there is no difference in their sound quality.

Comment: This sounds a lot like Chomsky's idea of absolute neutralization, at least in effect.

Comment: Reminds me of a story my aunt likes to tell about me as a toddler. "Whose toes are these?" she'd ask, tickling. "Yuke's toes!" I replied. She echoed me: "Yuke's toes?" only to get an indignant "No, not Yuke's toes! *Yuke's* toes!"

Answer (score 4):

This (strong absolute neutralization) is theoretically possible although has not yet been shown to exist. The closest case is Yawelmani, where the phonemes *u:, o:* are realized as [o:] everywhere. There is a well-known argument justifying the distinction, related to vowel harmony. However, the neutralization only applies to long *u*, and there are stem-forming shortening rules where /u:/ becomes [u] but /o:/ becomes [o], so the two phonemes are not realized the same way absolutely everywhere – there is a context where they are distinct. (There is also closed-syllable shortening where *u:* surfaces as [o] – shortening of *u:* to [u] only occurs as part of stem-formation).

As applied to second-language learning, this raises a question as to abstract competence versus concrete performance, and is analogous to the first-language acquisition problem that children may hear a certain distinction in phonemes but don't necessarily produce a distinction. This has proven to be difficult to verify experimentally, although anecdotally it is "verified" by the fact that adults seem to think that child English *r* is pronounced as [w] (at least, it sounds to adults less like proper adult *r* and more like *w*). There was a study (citation lost in the void) where it was shown that among the subjects that seemed to have *r→w* by adult judgment, articulation of *r* and *w* was nevertheless distinct. Anecdotally, some students of Lushootseed neutralized *ɬ* to *ʃ*, so that *ʃəgʷɬ* was pronounced *ʃəgʷʃ* (others may pronounce it *ʃəgʷθ*, keeping the phoneme distinct by mapping it to a different English phoneme). They did seem to know the spelling difference between *š* and *ɬ*; maybe their articulation of š-cum-ɬ different from that of regular *š*.